# fakeAsync not waiting for async operation to complete

Tags: angular, typescript, jasmine, karma-jasmine

## Context

I'm testing a component which is using an observable-based service to get some data and show it for i18n purpose.

The i18n service is custom because of a specific need.

The component works in dev mode (used in some templates, works fine) but the test fails.

## Source

#### Component

```
@Component({
    selector     : "i18n",
    template     : '<span [innerHTML]="text"></span><span #wrapper hidden="true"><ng-content></ng-content><span>',
    encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None
})
export class I18nComponent implements OnChanges {

    constructor(private i18n:I18n) {
    }

    @ViewChild('wrapper')
    content:ElementRef;

    @Input('key')
    key:string;

    @Input('domain')
    domain:string;

    @Input('variables')
    variables:Variables = [];

    @Input("plural")
    plural:number;

    text:string;

    ngOnChanges():any {
        this.i18n.get(this.key, this.content.nativeElement.innerHTML, this.variables, this.domain).subscribe((res) => {
            this.text = res;
        });
    }
}
```

#### I18n.get

```
public get(key:string,
               defaultValue?:string,
               variables:Variables = {},
               domain?:string):Observable<string>{
    const catalog = {
                         "StackOverflowDomain":
                         {
                             "my-key":"my-value"
                         }
                    };

    return Observable.of(catalog[domain][key]).delay(300);
}
```

with `Variables`:

```
export interface Variables {
    [key:string]:any;
}
```

## The test

```
describe("I18n component", () => {

    beforeEach(() => {
        TestBed.configureTestingModule({
            providers   : [
                I18n,
                {
                    provide : I18N_CONFIG,
                    useValue: {
                        defaultLocale : "fr_FR",
                        variable_start: '~',
                        variable_end  : '~'
                    }
                },
                {
                    provide : I18N_LOADERS,
                    useClass: MockLocaleLoader,
                    multi   : true
                }
            ],
            declarations: [
                I18nComponent
            ]
        });
        fixture = TestBed.createComponent<I18nComponent>(I18nComponent);
        comp = fixture.componentInstance;
    });

    fit("can call I18n.get.", fakeAsync(() => {
        comp.content.nativeElement.innerHTML = "nope";
        comp.key = "test";
        comp.domain = "test domain";
        comp.ngOnChanges();
        tick();
        fixture.detectChanges();
        expect(comp.text).toBe("test value");
    }));

});
```

## Problem

The test fails with message :

> Expected undefined to be 'test value'.
>
> Error: 1 periodic timer(s) still in the queue.

Because `i18n.get` did not finish its work before assertion has been checked, so comp.text is still `undefined`.

## Already tried

- Adding an very high value in `tick` method call, changed nothing (tried with 5000).
- Make `ngOnChanges` return a `Promise<void>` that resolves right after `this.text = res;` and change `fakeAsync` zone for a simple test using a `done` method caled in `then` of `comp.ngOnChanges`. It works, but `ngOnChanges` should not return a `Promise` and I want a clean solution.

Comment: Can you provide enough of a sample implementation of the `get` method to reproduce the problem. I am not sure how to implement it to get the error

Comment: I edited the question to add a mockup implementation for `i18n.get`

Comment: Does your real code actually use `delay`? The reason I ask is because I am trying to switch from using `fakeAsync` to `async` to see if that makes any difference, but it seems `delay` uses `setInterval`, which can't be used inside `async`.

Comment: my code isn't using delay, I just added it to simulate an async behaviour. but due to the async nature of Obervable it should work the same way without delay.

Comment: That's the thing. I got it working just fine just returning `Observable.of`. I had not problems. That's why I asked for an example the reproduced the problem :/

Comment: And I don't want to use a mock for I18n service, since those tests are my integration tests. Do we have any other way to introduce artificial delay in the `Observable`?

Comment: I don't know. Try your real code [with async](https://gist.github.com/psamsotha/2c3608ec9b6be423ed027fc2fda710b4). See what happens

Comment: I didn't find where the error came from but since I refactored everything by changing ̀text` type for an `Observable<string>` the issue is fixed. I let the question open in case someone finds out why I got this problem (since I wont be the last I guess)

Comment: add one more `tick();` after `fixture.detectChanges();`

Answer (score 6):

Note that `async` and `fakeasync` are not as powerful and inclusive as `jasmine.done`

Taking the exact note from (at the time of this writing): 
https://angular.io/guide/testing#component-fixture

It says:

> Writing test functions with done, while more cumbersome than async and
>   fakeAsync, is a viable and occasionally necessary technique. For
>   example, you can't call async or fakeAsync when testing code that
>   involves the intervalTimer, as is common when testing async Observable

Comment: Unfortunately, this content is not available at the provided URL anymore.